# jQuery Cycle Plugin - gaps between transitions in IE7

Tags: jquery, cycle

I am using the jQuery Cycle plugin and having trouble with gaps between the images when there should be smooth fade in/out transitions. This only happens in IE7.

I have seen the earlier postings about nesting the images in other elements to mask the fact that they are png images.

Is there a solution to make this transition smooth?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure SWAG but worth a shot, was one thing I have seen relating to some of the older jQuery versions was when using the effects I need to set my doc type to strict, that is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

The issue was when using the according plug-in in IE (didn't have the issue with Firefox) was the slide effect was jumpy and not smooth.

So there was something to the way IE 7 was rendering and I would love to have someone explain it to me.

This was BEFORE the jQuery UI library was available.

Answer (score 0):

try with transitional to fix problem NOT STRICT!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but there doesn't seem to be much information on the problem.   My problem was solved in IE7 by adding height & width to each slide plate.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the issue in compatibility mode in IE8 and IE9, to resolve it I removed min-height and min-width in my CSS.